# Remove Previous Line From Console QT5

Tags: qt, qt5

Is there any way in Qt5 to remove the previous line from the console when running a console application?

Like print a percentage from 1-100 on the same line overwriting each other?

Comment: `\r` (carriage return) will get you back to the start of the line. What are you using to print to the console?

Comment: \r did not work. I have tried using qDebug() and cout but neither have worked. I also could not figure out a way to use printf. Suggestions?

Comment: Yeah the problem with qDebug() is that it appends a new line at the end. You can use fprintf like this: `fprintf(stderr, QString("Text to print").toAscii().data());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this to show your percentage completed:

```
int percent = 1;
fprintf(stderr, QString("\rPercentage completed: %1").arg(percent).toLatin1().data());
```

Edit: toAscii() was removed in Qt5 so i replaced it with toLatin1() as suggested.

Comment: Only suggestion is in Qt5+ toAscii() has been removed. Have to use toLatin1() instead. Otherwise works perfectly.